# To-infinitive after "should"

Tags: to-infinitive

I have this question: Should we use the *to-infinitive* after should in this case?

- Should he (to) take his offer seriously, we will have to reconsider our proposal.

When should we and should not use '*to-infinitive*' after should in such constructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is with the auxiliary words "should/would/could/can/must" you need to use the so called "bare infinitive", without the word "to".

> Should he take his offer seriously, ...

However with other auxiliary words the situation might be different:

> Were he **to** take his offer seriously, ...